# MongoDB: Grouping documents according to criteria

Tags: mongodb

I am using Mongo 2.4. I have this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "place" : "52f06eb4a0a9210c11000032",
    "message" : "Hi"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "place" : "52f06eb4a0a9210c11000032",
    "message" : "Hi, how are you?"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "place" : "32f06eb4a0a9210c11000032",
    "message" : "?"
}
```

I need any method to group the documents by "place". Makes sense?

Comment: Does not make sense... What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Rishi I need to grouping the messages based on the place.

Comment: Do you want the messages to be accumulated into an array?

Comment: Yes, I want the result into an array sir.

Comment: I have got to be honest this is kinda "code to order" and we don't do that at SO, couldn't you have easily read the documentation yourself?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$place",
      messages: { $push: "$message" }
    }
  }
)
```

Example derived from the MongoDB docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push

Comment: YOu can check the result on mongotry: http://mongotry.herokuapp.com/#?bookmarkId=52fcd1db94ac2f02003dea1e